# Weird Glitch in Sibelius: violin pizz makes my clarinet and oboe parts sound like flute

Tags: sibelius

Pretty much what it says on the tin.  I have been orchestrating a piece for symphony orchestra and, whenever I put "pizz." in the violin I part, all of the sudden, my clarinet part is using a flute tone.  Nani?

Using general Midi.  Subscription version of Sibelius.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the case that the pizzicato plus the existing clarinet sound just happens to sound like a flute? Can you try to eliminate the pizzicato high frequencies as the cause by using really high violin pizz. and really low clarinet music (or maybe vice versa)?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing Sibelius, "pizzicato" requires a different instrument type than normal violin playing.  Maybe Sibelius is running out of Midi channels and sacrifices the channel it would use for clarinet?

The way to tell would be to look at the Midi file with some kind of Midi sequencing or viewing software.

Comment: There isn't a MIDI file.   We're working in Sibelius.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Technique Text, properly attached to the violin stave for your 'pizz.' instruction?

But you need to post the sib file if you want a definitive answer to this sort of question.   And you'd be better off in a specialised Sibelius forum.

As you have a subscription version of Sibelius, you're entitled to join the official Support forum at:

https://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3

Or there's a couple of Facebook groups.   See you there!